# Problem with select a rect element with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a problem with a panel development. The panel generates a bar graph for the current reading and draws lines for the lower and upper limits. This works great. Now I want to draw a sparkline to it. I first draw this sparkline in a separate div element below the actual graph.

In the graph I have two rect elements, one for the background and one for the actual bar. My goal now is to determine the size of the background rect element, then assign this size to my div for the sparkline and then place the sparkline div over the graph.

But the problem is that I can't access the rect element (it's just not found).

Hopefully my question is understandable. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code snippet:

```
  ...

  var panelID = "dd-multistat-panel-" + id;
  var tooltipDivID = "dd-multistat-panel-tooltip-" + id;
  var RectBackID = "dd-multistat-panel-back-" + id;
  var RectBackClass = "dd-multistat-panel-back-" + id;
  var RectBarID = "dd-multistat-panel-bar-" + id;

  ...

  // draw the background
      svg
        .append("g")
        //.attr("id", RectBackID)
        //.attr("class", RectBackClass)
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(stripedata)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("id", RectBackID)
        .attr("class", RectBackClass)
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", stripeScale.step())
        .attr("x", left)
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return stripeScale(d);
        })
        .attr("fill", "rgba(0,0,0,0)")
        .attr("stroke", OutlineColor)
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          if (showTooltips || Links.length /* && i < data.length*/)
            tooltipShow(d);
        })
        .on("mouseleave", function () {
          if (!isInTooltip) {
            tooltipHide(false);
          }
        });

  ...

  //my seach code
  
  var BarClassID = "." + panelID;
  var PanelBackID = "#" + RectBackID;
  var PanelBackClass = "." + RectBackClass;
  
  console.log("var findBar = d3.select(" + BarClassID + ")");
  var findBar = d3.select(BarClassID);
  console.log(findBar.nodes());      // --> finds 1 svg
  
  console.log("var findRect = findBar.selectAll(" + PanelBackID + ")");
  var findRect = findBar.selectAll(PanelBackID);
  console.log(findRect.nodes());     // --> finds 0 elements

  console.log("var findRect2 = d3.selectAll(" + PanelBackID + ")");
  var findRect2 = d3.selectAll(PanelBackID);
  console.log(findRect2.nodes());     // --> finds 0 elements

  console.log("var findRect3 = d3.selectAll(" + PanelBackClass + ")");
  var findRect3 = d3.selectAll(PanelBackClass);
  console.log(findRect3.nodes());     // --> finds 0 elements

  console.log("var findRect4 = d3.selectAll(svg)");
  var findRect4 = d3.selectAll("svg");
  console.log(findRect4.nodes());     // --> finds 55 svg

  console.log("var findRect5 = d3.selectAll(g)");
  var findRect5 = d3.selectAll("g");
  console.log(findRect5.nodes());     // --> finds 0 elements

  console.log("var findRect6 = d3.selectAll(rect)");
  var findRect6 = d3.selectAll("rect");
  console.log(findRect6.nodes());     // --> finds 0 elements
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of creating multiple svgs, you should create one svg and append your bar graph and spakrline to that.
In case you stick to same logic, try using `d3-selection` to select your `rect`.

```
import * as d3Select from 'd3-selection';
d3Select.select('#your-rect-id');
```

Here are some helpful links -

1. [ngx-charts](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/bar-vertical)
2. [Simple Bar Graph](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4)
3. [Graph Gallery](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/histogram_coloredTail.html)